# configuring a ssl for a web with specific script

Tags: php, apache, mod-rewrite

here is the config is going to add to httpd.conf, it never tested.

```
<VirtualHost facebook.domain.com:443>
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/html"
    ServerName domain.com
    ServerAlias facebook.domain.com
    ServerAdmin admin

    SSLEngine on

    SSLCipherSuite ALL:!ADH:!EXPORT56:RC4+RSA:+HIGH:+MEDIUM:+LOW
    :+SSLv2:+EXP:+eNULL

    SSLCertificateFile "/var/www/html/server.crt"

    SSLCertificateKeyFile "/var/www/html/server.key"

    <FilesMatch "\.(cgi|shtml|phtml|php|php5|php4|php3?)$">
       SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
    </FilesMatch>

    <Directory "path/to/cgi-bin">
       SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
    </Directory>
    SetEnvIf User-Agent ".*MSIE.*" \
        nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown \
        downgrade-1.0 force-response-1.0
</VirtualHost>
```

but i want to user when they browse http://www.domain.com/index.php?op=facebook will automatically redirect to https://www.domain.com/index.php?op=facebook or https://facebook.domain.com/index.php?op=facebook, how to achieve this?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
```

This will redirect all http -> https connections. You will have to add it to the http (:80) vhost.